# How do I get Ubuntu 15.10 to show the desktop version

Tags: dual-boot, apt, execute-command

I downloaded and installed Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Windows 8.1. Everything was fine and working.

Then I booted my computer and it goes to terminal, asks for login and then password, and then something like this pops up on black screen

```
tammy@tammy 1629 $~
```

So I'm assuming it's like a command line. I get nowhere fast. So I go and look up Linux commands and try to work it out. I can't get to the desktop version, I can't get `apt-get` to work, because everything I want to do says I need to install it via apt-get, things that are installed I can't access because they are locked, or could not be parsed or opened.

I cannot even use my USB ports, DVD, nothing so installing it again won't work. I can not even get back into Window 8.1 because I don't see the partition to know where it is.

So what I have here is a screen and a bunch of headaches and just when I think I can solve one of them, it leads me into another problem...

`apt-get install` ??? Says can't find file or it can't write to it cause its locked or its a read only or could not be parsed or open or exited with return code 1. I have  so many errors, so really don't know where to start.

Comment: Is it the "server" or the "desktop" edition of Ubuntu you had installed?

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu! You just entered the linux shell prompt

Comment: Maybe your system was mounted read-only. Could you provide more information about the error of "apt-get install"?

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed Ubuntu Desktop, use the command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

If it's Ubuntu Server,  I suggest installing lighter version of Unity desktop using the following command as it will exclude extras (e.g LibreOffice,...) of Ubuntu Desktop.

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

Restart Ubuntu once done

```
sudo reboot
```